# Remove weekends from Team WebAccess Burndown Chart (TFS 2013)

Tags: tfs, scrum

I have managed to remove weekends from the sprint burndown chart within the TFS report server however cannot get the change to reflect on the Web Access view.

Following some documentation online I have even made changes to the 'Sprint Burndown.rdl' report within the Scrum 2013 Process Template and uploaded this back into TFS however this didn't appear to change anything.

Has anyone managed to successfully remove weekends from this chart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Web Access module uses a different [location to store what weekdays are and which aren't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500408.aspx#weekend_days). You cannot remove weekends from the graph, [this is a much requested feature and according to the admin comment it is coming soon](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2792800-burndown-chart-should-exclude-non-work-days).

> UNDER REVIEW  ·   Visual Studio team
>
> Visual Studio team (Product Team, Microsoft) responded  ·  Aug 22, 2013:
>   We’re starting work on this and should be able to close it down soon. Stay tuned.

It might ship with TFS 2013 update 2 if they managed to fix this.

---

### Update

TFS 2013 update 2 RC now has the features to set Team Days off, which will effectively hide the weekends and these team days off from the burndown chart.

> Non-working days – Starting with Update 2, you can define you’re non-working days (weekends, for most of us) and we’ll exclude them from the burn down calculation so it no longer looks like you are on track when you really aren’t (because you don’t plan to work the weekend :)).

<sup>http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/02/05/vs-tfs-2013-2-update-2-ctp-released.aspx</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I have added my vote to the user voice link you supplied. Explains why everything I tried had no effect!

Comment: As of 22/01/2014 this has been added to Visual Studio Online via Update 2, but it has not yet made it into the full, self-hosted version of TFS: http://www.visualstudio.com/news/2014-jan-22-vso

Comment: TFS 2013 update 2 has removed the weekends, but broken my ideal line. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419090/tfs-scrum-burndown-showing-ideal-line-finishing-above-zero