# TFS Scrum Burndown showing ideal line finishing above zero

Tags: tfs, scrum, alm

I am using TFS 2013 and the Scrum 3.0 project template.

I have recently upgraded our TFS 2013 server to TFS 2013 update 2, in order to remove the weekends from our Sprint burndown graph.

The problem I have now is that the 'ideal' line no longer finishes at zero. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hmmmm.....a downvote with no comment. If the downvoter could explain why they downvoted then I could perhaps clarify or withdraw the question.

Comment: Pinged the product team and they will respond here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report of this. We have had a bug on this in TFS 2013 Update 2 RC that we fixed for RTM. Could you please verify your TFS version?

Ewald Hofman - TFS Program Manager

Comment: The version is 'Tfs2013.Update2.RC'....should I now install the RTM? I didn't know it had been released yet?

Comment: Silly me....it has been released. Looks like I installed the RC update  instead of RTM back in April. I'll install RTM and see how it goes.